# How can I get previous and next objects from a filtered, ordered queryset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a page based on a model object, and I want to have links to the previous and next pages. I don't like my current solution because it requires evaluating the entire queryset (to get the `ids` list), and then two more `get` queries. Surely there is some way this can be done in one pass?

```
def get_prev_and_next_page(current_page):
    ids = list(Page.objects.values_list("id", flat=True))
    current_idx = ids.index(current_page.id)
    prev_page = Page.objects.get(id=ids[current_idx-1])
    try:
        next_page = Page.objects.get(id=ids[current_idx+1])
    except IndexError:
        next_page = Page.objects.get(id=ids[0])
    return (prev_page, next_page)
```

Sort order is defined in the model, so doesn't have to be handled here, but note that you can't assume that ids are sequential.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like something the Paginator set to a threshold of 1 would do well at.

```
# Full query set...
pages = Page.objects.filter(column=somevalue)
p = Paginator(pages, 1)

# Where next page would be something like...
if p.has_next():
     p.page(p.number+1)
```

[Documentation here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/) and [here](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/pagination/).

Comment: Thanks, I was vaguely aware of the Paginator, but hadn't realized that I could use it like that (i.e. with a threshold of 1, in effect just wrapping the queryset in a Paginator object with the `has_next()`, `has_previous()` methods). The only thing missing is that I don't start at the beginning of the paginator range, but it looks like I can get this with `p.object_list.index(start_page)`.

Comment: This ended up not working well for me. The Paginator class really isn't made for traversing through objects.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to Python and Django, so maybe my code is not optimal, but check this out:

```
def get_prev_and_next_items(target, items):
    ''' To get previous and next objects from QuerySet '''
    found = False
    prev = None
    next = None
    for item in items:
        if found:
            next = item
            break
        if item.id == target.id:
            found = True
            continue
        prev = item
    return (prev, next)
```

And in view something like that:

```
def organisation(request, organisation_id):
    organisation = Organisation.objects.get(id=organisation_id)
    ...
    prev, next = get_prev_and_next_items(organisation, Organisation.objects.all().order_by('type'))
    ...
    return render_to_response('reference/organisation/organisation.html', {
        'organisation': organisation,
        'prev': prev,
        'next': next,
    })
```

Definitely not optimal for «heavy» querysets, but in most cases works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [django-next-prev](https://github.com/gregplaysguitar/django-next-prev), I wrote it to solve this exact problem. In this case:

```
from next_prev import next_in_order, prev_in_order

def get_prev_and_next_page(current_page):
    page_qs = Page.objects.all()  # this could be filtered, or ordered
    prev_page = prev_in_order(current_page, page_qs)
    next_page = next_in_order(current_page, page_qs)
    return (prev_page, next_page)
```

Comment: Raise an issue on the repo if you've found a problem