# Next previous links from a query set / generic views

Tags: django, view, pagination, generics

I have a quite simple query set and a related generic views:

```
f_detail = {
         'queryset': Foto.objects.all(),
         'template_name': 'foto_dettaglio.html',
         "template_object_name" : "foto",
       }

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# This very include
(r'^foto/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', list_detail.object_detail, f_detail, ),
)
```

Just a template for generating a detail page of a photo: so there's no view.

---

Is there an easy way to have a link to  previous | next element in the template 
without manualy coding a view ?

Somthing like a:

```
{% if foto.next_item %} 
  <a href="/path/foto/{{ foto.next_item.id_field }}/">Next</a> 
{% endif}
```

Comment: Mmh what do you want to know? Yes it is possible you already provided the solution. You just have to implement the method `next_item`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931008/is-there-a-clever-way-to-get-the-previous-next-item-using-the-django-orm

Comment: Saw that: if I understad it well it's about having a DateField  or DateTimeField in  the model, which is not my case: I'd like to order my queryset result by (let's say) the id field.


Is there a  preconfigured way to traverse the result set and get previous | next items? Or should I design my own views and code a _get_(next|previous)_item function?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
class Foto(model):
  ...
  def get_next(self):
    next = Foto.objects.filter(id__gt=self.id)
    if next:
      return next.first()
    return False

  def get_prev(self):
    prev = Foto.objects.filter(id__lt=self.id).order_by('-id')
    if prev:
      return prev.first()
    return False
```

you can tweak these to your liking. i just looked at your question again... to make it easier than having the if statement, you could make the methods return the markup for the link to the next/prev if there is one, otherwise return nothing. then you'd just do `foto.get_next` etc. also remember that querysets are lazy so you're not actually getting tons of items in next/prev.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was working on right now: a custom method for my model for the next/prev links. Thanks for the example, these (id__gt|lt=self.id) look much better then whathever I was thinking of.
Much appreciated.

Comment: `get_prev` and `get_next` return objects so had to use `foto.get_next.id` to get the pk of next/prev. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, btw. there's no need to check if `next` and `pref`. `first()` returns `None` if there's nothing found

Answer (score 7):

The `Foto` version above has a couple of shortcomings:

- Doing a boolean evaluation like `if next:` can be slow since it basically loads the entire `QuerySet` result.  Use `next.exists()` or the try/except like in my version.
- The `get_prev()` result is wrong because you need to reverse the ordering in this case.

So FWIW here is my version, which is for a generic primary key:

```
def get_next(self):
    """
    Get the next object by primary key order
    """
    next = self.__class__.objects.filter(pk__gt=self.pk)
    try:
        return next[0]
    except IndexError:
        return False

def get_prev(self):
    """
    Get the previous object by primary key order
    """
    prev = self.__class__.objects.filter(pk__lt=self.pk).order_by('-pk')
    try:
        return prev[0]
    except IndexError:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'll accept Model.objects.all() as your queryset, and you are ok with grabbing next / previous items by a date field (usually a 'created' field with auto_now_add=True will give the same order as object id's), you can use [get_next_by_foo() and get_previous_by_foo()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#django.db.models.Model.get_next_by_FOO), where 'foo' is the date field.

For next / previous links from a more complicated QuerySet, using the [Paginator with threshold set to one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692395/how-can-i-get-previous-and-next-objects-from-a-filtered-ordered-queryset) seems like it might be the best option.